# How do I partition new disk space after upgrading EC2 instance type?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I had created a `t1.micro` instance with an EBS volume attached to it. The volume was 8 GB. I stopped the instance and changed instance type to [`m1.medium`](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) which should have 410 GB of instance storage. When I do `df -h` on the instance, my output is

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  1.5G  6.4G  19% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Is there a way to partition/mount the 410 GB to the EBS volume? Or how can I get the rest of the instance storage to my use? (I'd like it to be part of the EBS so I it will be included in the snapshots)

Answer (score 1):

use the `resize2fs` command to expand the partition to take up the unused disk space.

Comment: I actually didn't end up using the instance storage. I resized an another bigger EBS volume from a snapshot of the 8 GB one and attached that to my instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`/dev/sdf`** as the mount point of the newly attached volume.

Check in the Details pane for thevolume, the state of the volume is *in-use*, and the volume is attached to your instance with the device name /dev/sdf. However **`df -h`** wont display the new volume.

Use **`lsbsk`**.  If the lsblk command does not work, you can use **`sudo fdisk -l | grep Disk`** instead.

*To make volume available:*

1. To mount the device as /mnt/my-data:

> [ec2-user ~]$ sudo mkdir /mnt/my-data
>
> [ec2-user ~]$ sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/my-data

2. Now run **`df -h`**

You are DONE now.